# 'AttributeError' when overriding 'RelatedField' in Serializing

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm working with a Django project that implement the Rest framework.

I have this model

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='???')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='portfolio', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Note on the 'owner' ForeignKey.

And in my `serializers.py` I have this

```
class MyRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
    return 'Test'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    portfolio = serializers.MyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'portfolio')
```

AS I read on the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield), I should override the `RelatedField` (which I did) if I want a custom representation. However when I try to run I get this error

`AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'MyRelatedField'`

No matter what I return in `MyRelatedField`, the same error occurs.

My question is how to debug and ideally, fix this error.
Thank you.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve with this is I'm trying for a more human-readable representation on the portfolios. First I was only hyperlinking but that would only show the urls, I want my field to show both the names and the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MyRelatedField and UserSerializer located in same module you need to replace `portfolio = serializers.MyRelatedField(many=True)` with `portfolio = MyRelatedField(many=True)`.

Comment: Thank you ! Was wondering why can't I find anything about it on the internet, probably because it was so obvious.